# Prove by induction that $r_0 + r_1a + r_2a^2 + \cdots + r_{n−1}a^{n−1} < a^n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction

> Let $a$ be a natural number greater than $1$. Prove that for all integers $r_0 , r_1 , \cdots , r_{n−1}$ with $0 ≤ r_j < a$, we have:
>   $$
> r_0 + r_1a + r_2a^2 + \cdots + r_{n−1}a^{n−1} < a^n
> $$

I am unable to prove the induction step.

Comment: Use induction on $n$.

Comment: @HarshCurious: Why bother to use induction? Just use the given inequality to upper bound each term.

Comment: @user21820 :The summation after that wouldn't give you the desired inequality.

Comment: @HarshCurious: That's not true. You can see that it would work as Adriano did. You could of course say that the induction is still in the summation but that's not the point.

Answer (score 3):

If you're required to use induction:

If the statement is true for $n=k$, then we have
\begin{align*}
r_0 + r_1a + \dots + r_{n-1}a^{n-1} + r_na^n &< a^n + r_na^n = (1+r_n)a^n.
\end{align*}
Now, if $r_n$ is an integer strictly less than $a$, then $r_n \leq a-1$, so ...

Answer (score 3):

Notice that since $a$ and each $r_j$ are **integers**, we know that:
$$
r_j < a \implies 1 + r_j \leq a \tag{$\star$}
$$
Now the induction step is easy:
\begin{align*}
r_0 + r_1a + r_2a^2 + \cdots + r_{n−1}a^{n−1}
&< a^{n-1} + r_{n-1}a^{n-1} &\text{by the induction hypothesis} \\
&= (1 + r_{n-1})a^{n-1} \\
&\leq (a)a^{n-1} &\text{by }(\star) \\
&= a^n
\end{align*}
as desired.